# How to Suitably Print Out Desired Output In MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I am writing a program in MATLAB for my Computer Science 1 class. We are only allowed to use what we have learned in class unless explicitly told otherwise. My knowledge of MATLAB is fairly small. In this program, I am trying to read from an Excel file using xlsread. The file has the names, like Day1, Day2, etc. in the rows, and the columns are machines. It's formatted like this, in general terms:

Day1 2 3\n (\n is not actually part of it, just for readability)
Day2 6 9\n
Day3 1 43\n

Somedays, the machines don't work, so no widgets are produced that day. In that case, it's NaN. The program takes the average (Not with a built in average function), and prints the output to another file. I need to find out how to do this. For all of the rows. I'm fairly certain it requires a for loop. Here's the code.

```
for r = 1: rows
    for c = 1: cols
        if isnan(machines(r, c)) == 0
            if(isnan >= blankDays)
                fprintf(output, '\nThe machine was not working for %f.1f%% of the days\n', blankDays);
            else
                fprintf(output, '\nThe average is %f.4f\n', myAverage);
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: P.S. If isnan is 10% of a whole column, then it should output differently to the file.

Comment: So far, it seems that you are asking us to do your homework. If this is not tha case, can you ask a specific question, and tell us why this code does not produce your desired output?

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of your previous question [How do I perform an if-statement on isnan to check for something?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74480339/how-do-i-perform-an-if-statement-on-isnan-to-check-for-something)